# Why Firefox cuts text vertically when other browsers don't?

Tags: html, css, firefox

[Live URL](http://www.doman.com.pl/zestaw-montazowy-na-3-gniazda-wallyflex-i-vroom) - look at "449 zł"

Firefox on Windows display is but from the top and from the bottom:

[image: 449 zł - cut]

Other browsers display this text ok.

I have tried different setting of `line-height, height, overflow` CSS properties for both `.regular-price` and `.price` elements, but with no luck.

What is the reason?

Comment: Cannot replicate in FF42 on W7

Comment: Screenshots generated on browserstack.com, Windows XP and 8.1: http://imgur.com/a/xk4Wv I have also seen it myself on my friend's up-to-date Firefox 42

Comment: Might be a font smoothing problem. I can't replicate it either (FF v42 on W7). Since the container with the class `.regular-price` is smaller than the font (at least for me), it seems maybe the font isn't rendered out past that container properly. Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Can't replicate on SeaMonkey 2.39 on Linux. Maybe the screenshot was not displayed at 100% size?